# how to stop current running activity while going to next activity

Tags: android, kill-process, taskkill

I have a "back" button in my current activity. As soon as i click it, it should stop the current task in activity and move to another activity. Here my problem is, it's moving to another activity but when that activity's task starts its getting crashed. I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(appPackageName);
```

Then i tried this, which didn't work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
//MyActivity.this.finish();
```

I tried `finish()` but that didn't work either.

Comment: override onDestroy() and in that override, cancel any running tasks.

Comment: well try MonitoringActivity.this.finish();

Comment: 03-03 16:34:57.060: E/AndroidRuntime(30562): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6795
03-03 16:34:57.060: E/AndroidRuntime(30562): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @kostasMatrix i tried that also its not working

Comment: post whole crash log. There is null pointer exception in your activity.

Comment: The official documentation on the android's activity lifecycle clearly states that when the activity is removed from the foreground after some successive lifecycle callbacks all code will stop executing. What exactly is the `task` that you perform that you want it to stop?

Comment: actually i want to start the new thread after stopping the current activity. sometime the crash will occur otherwise its coming to mainactivtiy as i wanted but for 5 -6 sec showing only black screen as if its going to crash

Comment: here is my complete log..   03-04 11:03:15.201:E/SQLiteDatabase(24528): 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 
19: constraint failed
03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):  at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert
(Native Method)
03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):  at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert
(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):  at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict (SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):

Comment: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert
(SQLiteDatabase.java:1713)03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):  at 
com.example.MyApp.db.DeviceDatabaseHandler.addDevice
(DeviceDatabaseHandler.java:73)
03-04 11:03:15.201: E/SQLiteDatabase(24528):  at 

com.example.MyApp.Thread.SendThread.run

(SendThread.java:62)
03-04 11:03:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(24528): FATAL EXCEPTION: 

Thread-9064
03-04 11:03:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(24528): 

java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:03:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(24528):  at 

com.example.MyApp.MyActivity$StatusThread.run

(MyActivity.java:449)